# Jquery DataTables syntax error

Tags: jquery, datatables

I use Jquery DataTables in my website. Now I want to add a Excel-Export function. I found the syntax for that on their website. For that it works.

But I have problems to fit my 2 code parts together:

My existing part:

```
<script>
  $(function () {
   // $("#example1").DataTable();
    $('#liste').DataTable({

     // When I try something like this:
     dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'excel'
       ]
     // the code do to NOT work at all

      "paging": true,
      "lengthChange": false,
      "searching": true,
      "ordering": true,
      "info": true,
      "autoWidth": false,
        "language": {
            "url": "../plugins/datatables/dataTables.german.lang"

        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

That is the part to display the export function:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#liste').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'excel'
       ]
  } );
} );

</script>
```

I use to put the "export-code" in my existing code, but then the whole table "do not work". I thing I stuck a little bit with the syntax.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show the version of the code that is broken? I haven't used `.DataTable()`, but wouldn't you just add the `dom` and `buttons` properties to the object you pass to the `.DataTable()` method in the first code block?

Comment: I still don't understand what is your actual problem,are you not able to integrate the codes see this [complete example](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/extensions/exportButtons.html)

Comment: I need to put the "excel code" inside the first code block. My problem is the JS "syntax bracket desaster". When I had two separate JS blocks DataTable say something like initial-error.

Comment: I edit the first code block to show what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

There should be comma after `buttons: [ 'excel' ]` block.

```
$('#liste').DataTable({
  "dom": "Bfrtip",
  "buttons": [
     "excel"
   ], 
  "paging": true,
  "lengthChange": false,
  "searching": true,
  "ordering": true,
  "info": true,
  "autoWidth": false,
  "language": {
     "url": "../plugins/datatables/dataTables.german.lang"
  }
});
```

Also don't forget to include appropriate files for Buttons extension. You can generate files to include on the [Download](https://datatables.net/download/index) page.